# How to implement twitter timeline in Windows Phone 8.1 using WebView?

Tags: twitter, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am a beginner in Windows Phone 8.1 app development. I want to implement a Twitter timeline in my app using `WebView`. I have the widget code which I got from Twitter when I created the widget in Twitter. I have put this code inside `HTMLPage1.html`. I only see "Tweets by @username" on my phone screen when I run the app. Tweets do not load.

**Code:**

**MainPage.xaml**

```
...
<Grid>
        <WebView Source="ms-appx-web:///html/HTMLPage1.html"/>

</Grid>
...
```

**HTMLPage1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/username" data-widget-id="DATA_WIDGET_ID">Tweets by @username</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Other similar posts/articles in Stackoverflow and other places are either unanswered or doesn't really address this issue. My guess is that I need to enable javascript in the `WebView` but, I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: Are you sure that the data widget Id you're including is correct? I tried it with my information and it worked properly both on the device and in the emulator. When I used an incorrect data widget Id that's when I noticed the behaviour that it only displays the "Tweets by..." without loading the widget.

Comment: @lori.lalonde Yes. It's correct.

Comment: No one has answer to a simple question. I will find the answer myself and update this thread. Meanwhile, if anyone wants to provide any solution/suggestion, he is welcome.